# Flutter widget tests cannot find InputDecoration.errorText

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-test

Note: this is for a Flutter web app.

I am testing a TextField to show that if the input is invalid, the error text specified on the InputDecoration is displayed.

The widget works appropriately when I run the entire app and interact with it manually.

Here's the definition of my TextField:

```
TextField(
  key: ValueKey('IntSpinner-TEXT'),
  controller: _controller,
  keyboardType: _keyboardType(),
  inputFormatters: widget.inputFormatters ?? [formatter],
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
    errorText: _validInput ? null : 'Invalid input',
  ),
);
```

I have a listener on the TextField's controller that examines the new value, and sets _validInput to true or false accordingly.

And here is the code for my test:

```
    testWidgets('should flag invalid values', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      int x;
      await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
        home: Card(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              IntSpinner( // this widget contains my TextField
                key: ValueKey('IntSpinner'),
                onChanged: (value) => x = value,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ));

      // Enter valid text
      await tester.enterText(find.byKey(ValueKey('IntSpinner-TEXT')), '-2200');
      expect(x, equals(-2200));

      // Enter invalid text
      await tester.enterText(find.byKey(ValueKey('IntSpinner-TEXT')), '2-200');
      expect(x, equals(-2200)); // unchanged!!
      
      TextField txt = tester.widget(find.byKey(ValueKey('IntSpinner-TEXT')));
      expect(txt.decoration.errorText, equals('Invalid input'));
    });
```

I get this error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TestFailure object was thrown running a test:
  Expected: 'Invalid input'
  Actual: <null>
   Which: not an <Instance of 'String'>
```

I see the same thing in the debugger -- inputDecoration.errorText is null. But when I run the app in the browser, I can clearly see (using the Flutter Widget Inspector) that errorText is set as expected (I also see the TextField being painted with the errorText).

Snippet of Widget Inspector output:

[image]

What is the proper way to check TextField.decoration.errorText from a Flutter widget test?

Comment: Is your listener setting the _validInput  correctly for initial value of controller.text which is "" (i.e. when you don't specify an initial value and don't type anything) ?

Comment: Yes. I actually provide an initial value which is valid. What's more, I can visually inspect the running app and all seems correct as far as whether the errorText is visible or not.

Comment: Can you make this test as your first test? I suspect the assignments done above to be causing this.

Comment: Done, and no difference. Still returns null for errorText.

Comment: Its a problem with the value of _validInput; I added a print('build:$_validInput'); statement at the top of my Widget.build() method, and it always prints "build:true".

Comment: With some more logging, I can see that I am setting _validInput inside a setState() closure, but the build method is never called after that change.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that works. I'd like someone knowledgeable to verify it.

The rebuild of the widget is not triggered when _validInput is set as the test is written. Instead, it seems to wait until I "complete" editing. I fake this by moving the focus off the TextField onto another TextField (using WidgetTester.showKeyboard(finder)).

So now my test steps are as follows:

```
      // print('Enter valid text');
      await tester.enterText(find.byKey(ValueKey('IntSpinner-TEXT')), '-2200');
      expect(x, equals(-2200));
      
      // move the focus somewhere else ... anywhere else
      await tester.showKeyboard(find.byKey(Key('FOO')));
      TextField txt = tester.widget(find.byKey(ValueKey('IntSpinner-TEXT')));
      expect(txt.decoration.errorText, isNull);

      // print('Enter invalid text');
      await tester.enterText(find.byKey(ValueKey('IntSpinner-TEXT')), '2-200');
      expect(x, equals(-2200)); // unchanged!!

      // move the focus somewhere else ... anywhere else
      await tester.showKeyboard(find.byKey(Key('FOO')));
      txt = tester.widget(find.byKey(ValueKey('IntSpinner-TEXT')));
      expect(txt.decoration.errorText, equals('Invalid input'));
```

This gets my test to work; the question is, why does errorText show up on the running app without moving the focus to another widget?

Comment: Regarding why the errorText doesn't show up in the test after entering the text - maybe you have to call `await tester.pumpAndSettle()` after `enterText()`?

Comment: `await tester.pumpAndSettle()` doesn't do the trick either